# MediaSessionCompat NullPointerException only on Android 8

Tags: java, android, crash, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

fellow community!

So I have a problem in my application, that is using MediaSessionCompat.

The problem which is a crash occurs only on Android 8 version (8.1 too), but mostly on 8.0.0 on different devices.

**Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.Reference.get()' on a null object reference**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.Reference.get()' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat$Callback$StubApi21.onCommand(MediaSessionCompat.java:955)
   at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompatApi21$CallbackProxy.onCommand(MediaSessionCompatApi21.java:164)
   at android.media.session.MediaSession$CallbackMessageHandler.handleMessage(MediaSession.java:1352)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:251)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6572)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I've searched through Google's Forums, where this problem was reported previously and through StackOverflow and hadn't succeeded.

Can someone give some tips or advices?

Comment: Provide your code .

Comment: The problem is that only on Android 8 and 8.1 when I start music and app is closed (only my Music Service is working)  i have Service being destroyed. onDestroy() in my Service calls unregistering of receiver, which is said not to be registered before. One more time, only Android 8+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved by updating to the latest support library version.

The answer was found somewhere deep in the bug-tracking forums of Google.

If someone will struggle with the same problem - try to update your support library version at least to the 27+ version.